# Unable to connect ODBC 32bit connection in Informatica

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle12c, informatica-powercenter

1. Created a ODBC data connection
2. Tested the coonection while creating and the alert box was displayed saying the connection was successful.
3. When opened the Source Analyzer[image] and tried connecting to Oracle driver created earlier, it throws architecture mismatch issue.

4.Powercenter client is of 32bit architecture and oracle driver created was on 64bit.

Please let me know how can I fix tihs....I am unable to fix this problem as the ODBC data source 32bit doesn't list the option of OracleDB2 drivers. Although this is available in ODBC data source 64bit when tried connecting the architecture mismatch errors pops up.

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

Regards,
Dex.

Comment: It seems you need to install the Oracle 32 bit driver. This is a seperate download. I did this recently and the package that I downloaded unzipped to a folder called `win32_11gR2_client`, and in the wizard I only installed the 'runtime' version. Make sure you install under the _same_ root folder but it's own subfolder. i.e. mine are under `D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\Client32` and `D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\Client64`

Comment: Is this the same case with Oracle 12C as well??

Comment: When you use a 32bit application then the Oracle Client must also be 32bit. A 64bit application requires a 64 bit Oracle Client. It applies for any release of Oracle. In case you need both, follow this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Yes pick the correct 32 bit client for your version of Oracle. The version will be reflected in the download file and install directory. What I'm getting at is it's neater if you stick all your client versions under one oracle root folder (in my case `D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0`). This isn't clear from the installer.

Comment: Also beware that when you are looking at the ODBC admin (to add/mod/delete your DSN) that -- depending on your version of Windblows, that there are separate admins for 32-bit vs 64-bit.  And there is no menu path to the 32-bit.  For details, see http://superuser.com/questions/419832/how-can-i-open-the-32-bit-odbc-data-source-administrator-in-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs. From begining I knew that this was 32bit-64bit comptability issue. I tried installing Oracle 32bit drivers for Oracle12C but just couldn't find the right resource online to do proper installation. At last I installed devart drivers for oracle, the installation was simple, just needed to run the exe file and it helped me connecting Informatica Powercenter Designer to Oracle database. The drivers are now compatible with both 32 bit and 64bit. Here is the link which I used:https://www.devart.com/odbc/oracle/download.html    ....... Thank You All! Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes the Oracle client driver install is a total nightmare form beginning to end and if you mess it up it's difficult to uninstall properly. Bad Oracle!

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error.Please follow the below to avoid this error.

1.Go to: $INFA_CLIENT_INSTALLATION_DIR\client\bin\
2.Open powmart.ini file
3.Under the section ODBCDLL,add Entry = PMODBC.DLL or EXTODBC.DLL

Then try to connect again!
This should work for sure.

Thanks,
Surya Prakash.